# Changing a jqGrid text column's editable property based on results of an autocomplete in another column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.4.0 with inline editing.  For the sake of this question, my grid has four columns: an ID column (SomeGridRowId), a text column with a jQuery autocomplete (Autocomplete), a single character text column (SingleChar), and a hidden `boolean` column (CanEditSingleChar).  I need to enable or disable editing of the single character column based on the value of the `CanEditSingleChar` column.  I've got this working on existing rows using `onSelectRow` and `setColProp`, but for some reason I cannot get it to behave correctly on newly inserted rows.  If I add a new row and select a value from the autocomplete, the `SingleChar` column is **always** not editable.  I've stepped through the Javascript using the Chrome and IE developer tools; the column values and properties are getting set properly, but the `SingleChar` column's `editable` property does not reflect this.

I apologize for the gigantic code snippet, but I don't want to leave anything out.

```
$("#coolGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetCoolGridData")',
    postData: {
        someId: function () { return $("#someId").val(); },
        otherStaticArg: function () { return 1; }
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    loadonce: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    scroll: true,
    pager: $("#coolGridPager"),
    rowNum: 200,
    sortname: 'SomeGridRowId',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    height: '100%',
    colNames: ['SomeGridRowId', 'CanEditSingleChar', 'Autocomplete', 'SingleChar'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'SomeGridRowId', index: 'SomeGridRowId', hidden: true },
        { name: 'CanEditSingleChar', index: 'CanEditSingleChar', hidden: true }, 
        {
            name: 'Autocomplete',
            index: 'Autocomplete',
            width: 220,
            editable: true,
            edittype: 'text',
            editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (elem) {
                    $(elem).autocomplete({
                        source: '@Url.Action("GetSomeGridAutocomplete")',
                        minLength: 2,
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            var rowId = getRowId($(this));
                            if (ui.item) {
                                $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'CanEditSingleChar', ui.item.CanEditSingleChar, '', '');
                                $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'Autocomplete', ui.item.label, '', '');
                                setSingleCharEditMode(rowId);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'SingleChar',
            index: 'SingleChar',
            width: 10,
            editable: true,     //default to true, most are editable
            edittype: 'text'
        }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function (clickedRow) {
        if (clickedRow && clickedRow != $.coolGridLastSelectedRow) {
            $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', $.coolGridSelectedRow, false, 'clientArray');
            $.coolGridLastSelectedRow = clickedRow;
        }
        setSingleCharEditMode($.coolGridLastSelectedRow);
        $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('editRow', $.coolGridLastSelectedRow, true);
    },
    afterInsertRow: function (rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
        if (rowid == 'new_row') {       //shown solely for completeness, pretty sure this is not the problem
            var newRowIndex = $("#coolGridNewRowIndex").val();
            if (!newRowIndex)
                newRowIndex = 1;
            var newRowId = rowid + "_" + newRowIndex;
            $("#new_row").attr('id', newRowId);
            newRowIndex++;
            $("#coolGrid").val(newRowIndex);
            $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('setSelection', newRowId, true);
        }
    }
});
$("#coolGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#coolGridPager',
{
    add: false,
    del: false,
    edit: false,
    search: false,
    beforeRefresh: function () {
        $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
    }
});
$("#coolGrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#coolGridPager',
{
    edit: false,
    add: true,
    addtext: "Add",
    save: false,
    cancel: false,
    restoreAfterSelect: false,
    addParams: {
        position: 'last',
        addRowParams: {
            keys: true
        }
    }
});
```

And the `setSingleCharEditMode` function:

```
function setSingleCharEditMode(rowid) {
    var rowData = $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
    if (rowData.CanEditSingleChar === "false") {
        $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('setColProp', 'SingleChar', { editable: false });
    } else {
        $("#coolGrid").jqGrid('setColProp', 'SingleChar', { editable: true });
    }
}
```

I've tried a whole slew of stuff, rifled through a pile of other SO questions, googled like mad....all to no avail.  I've resorted to pulling my hair out.  How can I control the `editable` property of one column after an autocomplete `select` on another column, all on a new row?

**EDIT**
I've got a [working example up here](http://goo.gl/MbFuS), finally.  If you add a row and then select either of the "Atypical *" in the `Autocomplete` column, you can reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without an actual example it is hard to tell why newly added rows can not be edited. Also, it is quite hard to put together a simple working example myself (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)) due to jqGrid and other dependencies.

A few questions after looking through your code that might help (or might be nothing new to what you already tried):

- **addRow** - How do you add a row, using the [`addRow` function](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#addrow)? Does everything else "jqGrid related" work with the newly added rows, i.e. does it get initialized properly? I had some issues with that kind of problem using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).
- **Correct / unique row id?** - Have you checked that the `rowid` is unique for new rows and that your
  code is executed with the correct one (i.e. the id from the new row)? Did you put `console.log` statements into `setSingleCharEditMode` to see what's going on (just to be sure, you said that you already stepped through the code)?

  You might be setting the `editable` property of a cell in
  another row *(Thinking about it: this can't be it, as the cell should be editable by default and the explicitely set to not being editable by your code.)*. Change the color of the row together with the `editable` property to easily see which cell/row is being worked on.
- **Working by default?** - As the default value of `editable` is `true`: have you tried
  disabling `setSingleCharEditMode` and see that the cell is editable
  by default? Maybe the problem isn't your evaluation but the adding of
  the row itself?
- **Correct type?** - In `setSingleCharEditMode` you test the column value for [strict
  equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) with the string "false". Are you sure that the values
  have the same type for existing and new lines (should be, as they are
  strings and get parsed through the same jqGrid code: `getRowData`)?
  I guess you already have `console.log`ged extensively in that function to see what is going on with the passed `id` and the comparison that sets the `editable` property[‽](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang)

Hope this helps a little to find the problem. As I said, it's really hard to debug without a working example. You might want to put one up somewhere.

**[Edit after working example]**

First thing I see is, that if you select "Atypical Manic Disorder" in an existing **editable** row, the same behaviour applies. Also: adding editable rows (Bipolar something) works. This does not seem to be a problem of "new row" vs. "existing row". More like a problem with editable rows that get changed to not editable.

My guess is that this is happening:

1. You are adding a new row, column `SingleChar` is editable by default, so the `<input>` is shown.
2. You evaluate the server response and set the column to `editable : false` in the autocomplete `select` handler.
3. You deselect the row and jqGrid reverts all **then editable rows**, so it doesn't touch `SingleChar`, because *it thinks* that `SingleChar` does not need to be reset to its initial state..

Am I making sense?

Try setting `editable` to `false` after jqGrid reset the row or removing the `<input>` yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response.  I'm working on getting an example online now.

Comment: Did you make any progress? And what do you think about assigning that bounty? I think there won't be any more answers before the grace period ends.

Comment: Sorry, Wolfram, hectic week last week and I didn't have time to get a fully working sample up.  I'm hoping to work on it today, but the bounty is yours (although I'm not sure why it split it to 100).

Comment: It was split as you didn't assign it during the grace period. No worries.

Comment: OK, working example is available, see the edit added to the OP.  Thanks again, Wolfram.