# jqGrid cell - How to dynamically set selected index of a dropdown and disable it

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my jqGrid, I have a row with two columns. Each column containing a drop down list. I am using inline editing. On change of first drop down list, I would like to set a selected value in the second drop down list and disable it. Here is the colModel for first drop down

```
{
     name:'pdInstanceType.id', 
     edittype:'select', formatter:'select', editable:true, 
     editoptions:{
         value:"1:Test1;2:Test2",
         dataEvents: [{ 
             type: 'change', fn: function(e) {
                 var valueToSet = 3;
                 var row = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                 var rowId = row.attr('id');
                 var secondSelect = jQuery('#' + rowId + '_stdCellLibrary.id');
                 secondSelect.val(valueToSet);//this is not working
                 //how to disable the secondSelect?
             }
         }]
     }
}
```

Here is the colModel for second drop down

```
{
    name:'stdCellLibrary.id', 
    edittype:'select', formatter:'select', editable:true, 
    editoptions:{
        value:"3:Test3;4:Test4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Finally, was able to figure this out. One way to retrieve a select drop down from a jqGrid cell is

```
var secondSelect = jQuery('#' + rowId + '_stdCellLibrary\\.id')[0];
```

I missed two things. Adding [0] and using double backslash when querying id with dot. Here is the complete solution for someone facing the same problem. Definition of second colModel remains the same. Here is the first colModel

```
{
    name:'pdInstanceType.id', 
    edittype:'select', formatter:'select', editable:true, 
    editoptions:{
        value:"1:Test1;2:Test2",
        dataEvents: [{ 
            type: 'change', fn: function(e) {
                var valueToSet = 3;
                var row = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                var rowId = row.attr('id');
                var secondSelect = jQuery('#' + rowId + '_stdCellLibrary\\.id')[0];
                jQuery(secondSelect).val(valueToSet);
                //how to disable the secondSelect
                jQuery(secondSelect).attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Cool, glad you figured this out.  Make sure you mark it as the accepted answer when you are able to.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of the second select you should use jqGrid's `setCell` method ([jqGrid wiki methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)).

```
var rowId = $("#nameOfGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
$("#nameOfGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'stdCellLibrary.id', valueToSet);
```

I have had limited success disabling columns based on value changes in other columns.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11215942/27457) for more information.

Comment: The above code, replaces the drop down with valueToSet. So the cell now contains a text instead of a drop down

Comment: If I use `jQuery('#' + rowId + '_stdCellLibrary.id').prop("selectedIndex", 1);` it updates the select drop down. Unfortunately, I do not know the index that I want to set. I only have the value of the option that I want to set. May be it is more of a jQuery question